# Ember Data @each vs firstObject discrepancy

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Maybe I'm misunderstanding '@each'.

Why would the is the @each selection array empty

```
this.get('taggings.@each.selection').toArray()
[]
```

but the firstObject is present:

```
this.get('taggings.firstObject.selection.id')
"528d0f2b6dc8270d2f0002df"
```

Similarly, I can do this:

```
this.get('taggings').toArray()[0].get('selection.id')
"528d0f2b6dc8270d2f0002df"
```

but I would rather write the more succinct 'taggings.@each.selection'

Here is some more context:

```
App.Folder = DS.Model.extend(App.Auditable, {
  //....
  taggings: DS.hasMany('tagging', {async: true}),
  //...
  selections: function() {
    return this.get('taggings.@each.selection');
  }.property('taggings.@each'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@each is used for denoting dependency (in the property method), not as a getter.

There are some nice methods that will map up results though.

```
this.get('taggings').map(function(tagging){return tagging.get('selection')});
```

or even smaller

```
this.get('taggings').getEach('selection');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AlUjAVo/1/edit